# Network interface and IP aliasing

Tags: networking, ip-address, network-interface

This is more like confirmation of my understanding, I have a Linux server and I wanted to know how many IP addresses and how many NIC's it have, so I used `ifconfig` command, now I see below output.

```
[hagrawal@dc4cmb ~]$  /sbin/ifconfig -a | grep HWadd
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 55:3E:A2:04:82:58  
eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 55:3E:A2:04:82:58  
eth0:2    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 55:3E:A2:04:82:58  
eth0:3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 55:3E:A2:04:82:58  
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 55:3E:A2:04:82:5A  
eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 55:3E:A2:04:82:5C  
eth3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 55:3E:A2:04:82:5E  
[hagrawal@dc4cmb ~]$
```

**Questions:**

- Does it mean my server has total of 4 NICs i.e. eth0, eth1, eth2 and eth3?
- Does it mean that first NIC has 4 IP address associated with it?
- If above is true then this is what you call it as ["IP Aliasing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_aliasing)?

Now, below is another output on same system:

```
[hagrawal@dc4cmb ~]$ /sbin/ifconfig -a | grep "inet addr"
          inet addr:172.24.200.160  Bcast:172.24.203.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet addr:172.24.200.211  Bcast:172.24.203.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet addr:172.24.200.213  Bcast:172.24.203.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet addr:172.24.200.214  Bcast:172.24.203.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
[hagrawal@dc4cmb ~]$
```

**Questions:**

- I have not pasted complete output but I can tell you have above IP addresses are from "eth0", "eth0:1", "eth0:2" and "eth0:3", so does it mean that my only 1st NIC i.e. "eth0" is connected to a network while other 3 NICs i.e. "eth1", "eth2" and "eth3" are not connected with network but **simply present on the motherboard of my Linux server**?

---

**Complete log:**

```
[hagrawal@dc4cmb ~]$ /sbin/ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 55:3E:A2:04:82:58  
          inet addr:172.24.200.160  Bcast:172.24.203.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:925589674 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:976952984 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:247406781407 (230.4 GiB)  TX bytes:359023543671 (334.3 GiB)
          Interrupt:123 Memory:a4000000-a4011100 

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 55:3E:A2:04:82:58  
          inet addr:172.24.200.211  Bcast:172.24.203.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:123 Memory:a4000000-a4011100 

eth0:2    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 55:3E:A2:04:82:58  
          inet addr:172.24.200.213  Bcast:172.24.203.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:123 Memory:a4000000-a4011100 

eth0:3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 55:3E:A2:04:82:58  
          inet addr:172.24.200.214  Bcast:172.24.203.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:123 Memory:a4000000-a4011100 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 55:3E:A2:04:82:5A  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
          Interrupt:178 Memory:f2000000-f2012800 

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 55:3E:A2:04:82:5C  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
          Interrupt:226 Memory:f8000000-f8012800 

eth3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 55:3E:A2:04:82:5E  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
          Interrupt:234 Memory:f6000000-f6012800 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:4969897596 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4969897596 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1378529138243 (1.2 TiB)  TX bytes:1378529138243 (1.2 TiB)

[hagrawal@dc4cmb ~]$
```

---

**PLEASE DO NOT ANSWER** IF YOU ARE NOT 100% SURE AND NOT A N/W EXPERT, BECAUSE I AM ALREADY CONFUSED AND I DO NOT WANT TO GET MORE CONFUSED OR END UP WITH WRONG INFORMATION.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ip addr` to show addresses, not ifconfig.  The ifconfig command is using a deprecated interface and can lie to you.  Also see `ip link`, and other `ip` related commands.

> Does it mean my server has total of 4 NICs i.e. eth0, eth1, eth2 and eth3?

This is a bit tricky to answer.  A network interface controller can have multiple ports.  Do you count a 4 port network interface controller as a single NIC, or as 4 nics?  Given that the 4 mac addresses of your interfaces are all nearly identical, I would bet you have a quad port controller either installed or on the motherboard.

If you really want to know about the **physical** controllers, you should be looking at the output of **`lshw`**, not `ifconfig` or `ip link` which have more of a logical view of setup.  A single physical interface can be used for many virtual interfaces.  So looking only at the output of ifconfig cannot necessarily give you a real understanding of the system because with Linux, you can do really complicated and unusual things.

> Does it mean that first NIC has 4 IP address associated with it?

Not necessarily, but probably.  Unfortunately your grep removed some of the information, that would help answer that question.

> IP Aliasing"?

IP alaising is an early somewhat hacky method that permitted the kernel to have multiple IPs associated with a single interface. The `ifconfig` binary will only see multiple addresses if you are  using the aliasing method.  But if you use the newer `ip addr` tool you can assign as addresses without messing around with aliases.  On newer kernels the 'aliases aren't even really aliases anymore.  They are just another IP associated with the interface that also has an associated label.

If you run `ip addr show dev eth0` will probably see all ~4 of the addresses associated with that interface/port.

Comment: Thank you for your time to reply and all useful information you have given in your answer. I have updated my question with comeplete information so that I could get more helpful information from you. I couldn't execute 'ip link' or any other 'ip' related commands and even 'lshw', looks like these commands are not installed on my Linux box. Below are few follow up questions:

Comment: "***Do you count a 4 port network interface controller as a single NIC, or as 4 nics?***" - Suppose https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_interface_controller#/media/File:ForeRunnerLE_25_ATM_Network_Interface_(1).jpg this had 4 ports, so I would still count it as 1 NIC with 4 ports, because this is one hardware piece, is it wrong? ......

Comment: "***Given that the 4 mac addresses of your interfaces are all nearly identical, I would bet you have a quad port controller either installed or on the motherboard.***" - for "eth0", "eth0:1", ""eth0:2" and ""eth0:3", MAC addresses are same but for "eth1", "eth2", "eth3" they are different so I am assuming that "eth0" is one NIC (by understanding of NIC is in above comment) and "eth1", "eth2", "eth3" are 3 more NIC's

Comment: I didn't understood your point about "aliases" in the end, where are aliases in my output of `ifconfig`, you mean this - `eth0:1`? If so then you mean using `ip addr`, these kind of aliases will not be there? Then how will be the output and how I could know that these are IP address associated with the same NIC, this looks clear to me using `ifconfig` command, could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: Could you please let me know your inputs for above questions.

Comment: ` I couldn't execute 'ip link'` - What type of Linux box are  you running?  What distro, what release?  You really figure out why those tools aren't available, and install them and look a the results.  The output from those commands will be less confusing.

Comment: I am running on Redhat Enterprise Linux, I cannot install any  command on those server because it is not in my control, so could you please let me know the answers of my questions, whenever you have little time.

Comment: Could you please let me know if you could answer my questions? I have `cygwin` on my Windows box I thought I would install `ip` command using it on my windows box and see how it works, but I could get it, so I guess I would need my answers from someone.